# ¿Los Fiddles están deshabilitados?

Tags: soporte

Veo las preguntas y no hallo la opción de agregar un fiddle que normalmente se encuentra en la parte superior para poner un código que se pueda ver y ejecutar.

¿Está deshabilitado para nuestra comunidad por ser pequeña o es un límite debido a la reputación?